# Regexp c++ doesn't match greek characters

Tags: c++, regex

This regular expression

```
RE re("(?<![" ALNUM ",:\\.\\/-])([Μμ]έρος|[Σσ]υνεδρία|[Κκ]εφάλαιο|[Αα]ριθμός|[Ππ]ράξη|[Ττ]όμος|[Ππ]αράγραφος) ([IVXLCDM]+)(?![" ALNUM "\\$£€-])");
```

matches "τόμος I", but

```
RE re("(?<![" ALNUM ",:\\.\\/-])([Μμ]έρος |[Σσ]υνεδρία |[Κκ]εφάλαιο |[Αα]ριθμός |[Ππ]ράξη |[Ττ]όμος |[Ππ]αράγραφος )([ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϞϠ]+)(\\')?(?![" ALNUM "\\$£€-])");re
```

doesn't match "τόμος Α'" or "τόμος Α".

Any guesses on why? I've re-written it in Python, Golang and Javascript and it works, but in C++ it doesn't match. I also tried matching the utf-8 character but still nothing. Any guesses on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `(?<!...)`  can't work in Go, unless you use a PCRE regex library. Go's RE2 library does not support any lookarounds.

Comment: Hi! I know, I just stated that I find it weird that it works when i RE-write in other languages but in C++ it doesn't. My code here is C++ not Golang

Comment: These MACRO or whatever aren't helpful. Write that can be tested. Also, there was some lack of utf8 support in stl. Try utf16 instead.

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: If it is for `std::regex`, nothing weird, it is based on ECMAScript 262 that does not support lookbehinds. JS that supports ECMAScript 2018+ (Chrome, Node.js, Opera, Samsung Internet, etc.) supports them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does none of the regex flavours available in C++ support lookbehinds?

Comment: If you mean `std::regex`, no. You may use it with `boost::regex`